# Mysql: replace string in one table based on information on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, str-replace

I have the following problem, this is going to be long, I want to tell exactly all what I know about my problem in my question.

I have a table, field_body_value, with two fields, body_value and body_summary, containing strings of the form "/webfm_send/#" where # is a number.

I have another table called webfm_file where I have two fields with information for the string substitution: the first one is called fid, and it is the number # that I mentioned before, and the second is called fpatch, and gives me a string holding a path (for instance /data/html/files/file1.pdf) which has to substitute /webfm_send/# in the first table. The numbers # go up over the records of webfm_file but there are jumps, that is they increase but there are missing # so the final # is not equal to the number of records in webfm_file

So I thought the strategy was to set up a procedure which loops over the second table, and at each step of the sequence retrieves the pair fid/fpath, searches for "/webfm_send/fid" in the first table, and substitutes this by fpath in the first table.

So this is as far a I could arrive with my coding:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @numrec FROM `webfm_file`;
  WHILE v1 < @numrec DO
    SELECT fpath,fid INTO @path,@file FROM `webfm_file` LIMIT v1,1;
    SET @webfm = concat('/webfm_send/',@file);
    SET @cpath = concat('/',@path);
    UPDATE `field_data_body`
    SET body_value = replace(body_value, @webfm, @cpath),  
    body_summary = replace(body_summary, @webfm, @cpath)
    WHERE body_value LIKE concat('%',@webfm,'%') OR 
    body_summary LIKE concat('%',@webfm,'%');
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Let me explain what I think I'm doing with the code above:

1) I retrieve the number of records in webfm_file for the loop.

2) The first SELECT gets a pair in fpath/fid from webfm_file, with LIMIT v1,1 I just check one record at a time, I checked an it works, the while loops over each record of webfm_file and the records are retrieved correctly.

3) The two next "set" fix the pair of strings  @file/@path to create @webfm whith is the way its written in body_value at field_body_value, and to put a slash in front of @cpath which is the way I need this string to finally appear.

4) Then comes the UPDATE which will actually substitute the string if it finds it in either body_value or body_summary of field_body_data.

Expected: each instance of /webfm_send/# is substituted by the corresponding fpath pair of # (fid) in webfm_file

What I actually get: All appearances of /webfm_send/# no matter the value of # are substituted by the value of fpath in record 1 of webfm_file.

Things I have tried:

1) Take out the "WHERE" clause in the UPDATE sentence, which I believe is not strictly necessary since the replace function already takes care of finding a match but could speed up things. Same result

2) Resctrict the loop to loop just over a single record of webfm_file. Here it works in substituting the corresponding single retrieved pair fid/fpath, in the two instances of body_value and body_summary in field_body_data where fid=# appears in the string webfm_send/#

Thanks for following my explanation until here and thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cursor to iterate over the replacement strings. (There are faster ways using group_concat and it would be easier to do this in a general-purpose language rather than in a stored procedure). The general cursor approach would be:

```
drop procedure if exists proc;
delimiter //

create procedure proc()
begin
  declare done boolean default 0;
  declare path varchar(255);
  declare id int;
  declare cur cursor for select fpath, fid from webfm_file order by fid desc;
  declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done = 1;

  open cur;

  block: loop
    fetch cur into path, id;

    if done then
      leave block;
    end if;

    set @from = concat('/webfm_send/', id);

    update field_data_body set
      body_value = replace(body_value, @from, path),
      body_summary = replace(body_summary, @from, path);
  end loop;

  close cur;
end//

delimiter ;

call proc();
```

Comment: Thanks jspcal, but your routine does exactly the same as mine. It substitutes all instances of `@from`in field_data_body by the value of the first record of `path` in webfm_file. If I put      SELECT @from;      SELECT path;  then I see the routine iterating over the correct values, but somehow in the `UPDATE` clause `@from` is being iterated correctly (all the instances `webfm_send\#`are found) but `path` not.

Comment: That's odd - it works for me. Your issue may be that the string `/webfm_send/1` also matches any ID starting with `1` (10, 11, etc.) and so will end up replacing those as well. To deal with that, select the path entries in descending `fid` order.

Comment: Thanks again jspcal, that's it! So stupid to not see that for instance `webfm_send/1` was matching also `webfm_send/11`, `webfm_send/111` and `webfm_send/1111`. But as these strings appear in `field_body_data` surrounded by quotes, it was as easy as changing the match to `webfm_send\#"` and it worked. The conclusion in any case is that both your code and mine work exactly the same way, yours is more elegant though, but not faster (they both have exactly the same loop). In wonder finally if the same could have been achieved with a JOIN of the two tables and no loop.